# Elasticsearch POST hangs and never returns

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having an odd problem with an ElasticSearch cluster.  All of a sudden POST operations to add documents to an index just hang and never return.  The client times out, however I used fiddler to manually test the call, and it never returns.  What would cause ElasticSearch to just hang when indexing a document and never return a response?

Comment: I should note this is a 3 node cluster, with maybe 2GB of data total.  The cluster status was green, and I see no evidence of any errors.   I have no idea where to start looking.  I have 144 primary shards, could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what client technology you're using and show an sample query you're doing?

Comment: This could probably be due to too many shards. 144 is a very big number especially when you consider you have only 3 nodes and **only** 2GB data. Every single shard is a lucene index and uses file handles, memory, and CPU cycles. [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/capacity-planning.html) is a good article on capacity planning. Also [write consistency](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-consistency) needs to be maintained for every index operation. You might want to increase `timeout`.

Comment: Thanks.  The client technology is basically curl.  I was running the request through fiddler.  I am doing daily logs for some off the data, so maybe I should switch to monthly indexes until I have more volume.